# In Asp.net 4.0, In the Paging enabled grid, How to retain text box values when we navigate back from another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

In Asp.net 4.0 (C#), In the Paging enabled grid, How to retain text box values when we navigate back from another page?

1. I have a databound grid with labels and textboxes
2. I have entered some values in some textboxes
3. I navigate to another page and do the same
4. I return to old/previous page and i couldn't find those edited values in text boxes.

I have to retain the textbox values even if i navigate across multiple pages in the grid.

Please provide me a simplest solution to do this.

This is the code:

```
    protected void grdSgnageEntries_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        lblErrorMessage.Text = string.Empty;
        int JkpId = 0, LinkLevelId = 0;

        if (Convert.ToInt32(ddlSnapShotType.SelectedValue.ToString()) == (int)SnapshotTypes.JackpotHit)
        {
            JkpId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlJackpotInstances.SelectedValue.ToString());
            LinkLevelId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlLevels.SelectedValue.ToString());
        }
        grdSgnageEntries.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        FillSgnageEntriesGrid(LinkLevelId, JkpId);
        grdSgnageEntries.DataBind();
    }
    catch (FormatException exp)
    {
        lblErr.Text = "Invalid Date";
        grdSgnageEntries.DataSource = null;
        grdSgnageEntries.DataBind();
        btnSubmit.Visible = false;
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        bc.LogExceptionToDB(exp);
    }
}

protected void grdSgnageEntries_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            ((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtAmount")).Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "javascript:return MyKeyPress();");

            if (((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtAmount")).Text != string.Empty)
            {
                ((TextBox)e.Row.FindControl("txtAmount")).Enabled = false;
                btnValidate.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                btnValidate.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        bc.LogExceptionToDB(exp);
    }
}
protected void btnGetLevels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    ds = bc.getJackpotInstancesForSignageEntry(Convert.ToInt32(ddlLinks.SelectedItem.Value), Convert.ToDateTime(txtEntryDate.Text.ToString()), Convert.ToInt32(ddlSnapShotType.SelectedValue.ToString()), LinkLevelId, JkpId);
    Session["gamingDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(txtEntryDate.Text.ToString());

    if (ds.Tables.Count > 1)
    {
        grdSgnageEntries.Columns[0].Visible = true;
        grdSgnageEntries.DataSource = ds.Tables[2];
        grdSgnageEntries.DataBind();
        grdSgnageEntries.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        btnSubmit.Visible = true;
        btnValidate.Visible = true;
        btnSubmit.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can only do this opening the new page in a pop-up then close it.

Comment: @WAP Guy - How are you navigating to the next page, how on button click ?

Comment: I meant pages within a grid having Previous Next Buttons

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in the Session for example:

```
// Save before going to another page: 
Session["FirstName"] = FirstNameTextBox.Text;

// Load when coming back to the page:
FirstNameTextBox.Text = (string)Session["FirstName"];
```

More details here: [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

Comment: No.I meant pages within a grid having Previous Next Buttons